# Trouble creating GPA calculator

Tags: go

I want to make a GPA calculator which first ask users to input their total credits for the semester. I achieved to do so. Then I want to take total subjects as input from user which I am able to do too. But now comes the real problem. I want to take input from user in the following form :-
"Math":"A", "Physics":"B"
Then to calculate GPA I want to do the following conversion from respective grade to score 
Like S = 10, A = 9, B = 8, C = 7 and use it to calculate their GPA with the equation

GPA = Total Score { Credit of subject * respective grade score} / Total credit

So if a student has 2 subjects Math and Physics and credit for Math is 4 and he scores S and credit for Physics is 3 and he scores C then GPA will be :-

GPA = 4(credit of Math) * 10(grade score for S) + 3(credit of Physics) * 7(grade score for C) / 7(Total Credits)

code below :-

```
package main

import "fmt"
var gpa float64

func main() {
    // Schema
    var totalCredit float64
    var totalSubjects int
    var letterGrade string
    var credit float64
    var score float64
    var totalScore float64
    // Takes value of credits and subjects from user
    fmt.Print("Enter total credits")
    _, _ =  fmt.Scan(&totalCredit)
    fmt.Print("Enter total number of subjects")
    _, _ =  fmt.Scan(&totalSubjects)
    n := totalSubjects


    for i:=0; i < n; i++ {
        fmt.Println("Enter letterGrade")
        _, _ = fmt.Scanf("%s", &letterGrade)
        fmt.Println("Enter credits")
        _, _ = fmt.Scan(&credit)
        if letterGrade == "S" || letterGrade == "s" {
            score = credit * 10
        } else if letterGrade == "A" || letterGrade == "a" {
            score = credit * 9
        } else if letterGrade == "B" || letterGrade == "b" {
            score = credit * 8
        } else if letterGrade == "C" || letterGrade == "c" {
            score = credit * 7
        } else if letterGrade == "D" || letterGrade == "d" {
            score = credit * 6
        } else if letterGrade == "E" || letterGrade == "e" {
            score = credit * 5
        } else if letterGrade == "F" || letterGrade == "f" {
            score = credit * 0
        }
        totalScore += score
    }
    gpa = totalScore / totalCredit
    fmt.Println(gpa)
}
```

I want to create the above using OOP in GO.

Comment: I think this is a logic problem, you actually don't need to USE which subjects user has, you just need their grades per subject. Can you share sample code?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "I want to create the above using OOP in GO." - that's going to be difficult, as Go is not an object-oriented language.

Comment: @Adrian then tell me how to write it in GO way :)

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing service. If you have some specific question or bug, that's something that the community could help with. "Here's my requirements, how do I implement this" is too broad for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a plausible Programming 101 student solution to this looping construct assignment:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

var grades = map[string]float64{
    "S": 10,
    "A": 9,
    "B": 8,
    "C": 7,
    "D": 6,
    "E": 5,
    "F": 0,
}

func main() {
    totalCredits := 0.0
    totalScore := 0.0

    var subjects int
    for {
        fmt.Println("Enter number of subjects:")
        n, err := fmt.Scan(&subjects)
        if n == 1 && err == nil {
            if subjects >= 0 && subjects <= 20 {
                break
            }
        }
    }

    for i := 0; i < subjects; i++ {
        var grade float64
        for {
            var letterGrade string
            fmt.Println("Enter letter grade:")
            n, err := fmt.Scanf("%s", &letterGrade)
            if n == 1 && err == nil {
                var ok bool
                grade, ok = grades[strings.ToUpper(letterGrade)]
                if ok {
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        var credits float64
        for {
            fmt.Println("Enter credits:")
            n, err := fmt.Scan(&credits)
            if n == 1 && err == nil {
                if credits >= 0 && credits <= 10 {
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        totalCredits += credits
        totalScore += credits * grade
    }

    gpa := 0.0
    if totalCredits != 0.0 {
        gpa = totalScore / totalCredits
    }
    fmt.Println("GPA:", gpa)
}
```

Output:

```
$ go run gpa.go
Enter number of subjects:
2
Enter letter grade:
A
Enter credits:
3
Enter letter grade:
b
Enter credits:
4
GPA: 8.428571428571429
$
```